# C# XNA Xbox, in this case optional parameters are not optional

Tags: c#, parameters, xna, optional-parameters, xbox

Apparently optional parameters won't work in C# Xna when used on the Xbox, there non suportedness is stated during compilation.

I have a situation like this:

```
func(float? a = null, int? b = null)
```

With large numbers of thease optional parameters that default to the "undefined" value, null. This situation is required.

In the simplified example above this can be unwrapped, although this isn't as optional parameters allow:

```
func()
func(float? a)
func(int? b)
func(float? a, int? b)
```

However with large numbers of parameters this isn't practical.

Some combinations of parameters definedness isn't permitted and results in paths through the function where I throw argument exceptions, others result in various different things occurring depending on the values of the parameters. This is similar to polymorphism between functions with the same name but is not the same.

I could alternatively, and probbably most practically, require all the parameters instead.

```
func(float? a, int? b)
```

Then call as so:

```
func(null, 4)
```

Where the first is undefined.

Instead of using one of the above bodges, is there a way to enable optional parameters in C# XNA on Xbox?

Comment: Have you considered passing in a class object rather than 15 parameters that may or may not be required? Seems like that would solve your issue and give you the most flexibility.

Comment: I'd have to construct the class and than define some of it's parameters probbably on many seprate lines of code, or using a constructor or other member function that itself had optional parameters. It's not a bad idea, not as good for me as optional parameters but great compaired to the func(null, 4) solution from the point of view of not having an order of parameters that must stay the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've certainly run on the XBOX with optional parameters, but it required some tweaking of the build settings.  From what I recall it will not work with WP7 however.

I think it might have been related to the Language Version being used.

Check out the following links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff827884.aspx

http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/54007/327944.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I would use old-fashioned overloads that take different numbers of parameters, and forward the calls on from there, along with the "default" values. Zero code changes to the callers.

If the types are outside your control: extension methods to add the overloads.

Comment: Difficult where there are, for example 15 optional parameters being simulated.

Comment: In this case 32,768 verstions of the function seems excessive.

Comment: It would also be nice still to be able to define in any order on use.

Comment: @alan yes, don't write all 15k - but I suspect in reality only a subset are in use

Comment: Thanks, working out the subset could be very complicated, would still be a long list and would change some of the times that the function changed. I'm not going to try this :¬P but thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can enable the optional parameters. Maybe you can use an alternative. like the params keyword that creates an array, you could just pass an object as parameter

```
public class MyParams 
{
     public float? a {get;set;}
     public int? b {get;set;}
}

func(new MyParams { b = 5 });
```

With that solution, you have all the flexibility you might want. You can add, remove parameters without thinking of adding/removing new overload. And if you remove or edit a parameter, you'll get a compile time error, something you might not get with multiple overload.

Comment: This is probably unacceptable in an XNA game on Xbox 360, where allocating memory is often a big no-no.