# C# HashSet2 to work exactly like the standard C# HashSet, not compiling

Tags: c#, collections, xna, hashset, xbox

I'm creating my own HashSet that works as the standard HashSet, using a Dictionary. I'm doing this because C# for XNA XBox doesn't support HashSets.

This code is based on code from an example I found. I've edited the example to fix some of the problems but it still won't compile.

```
public class HashSet2<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, Int16> dict;

    // code has been edited out of this example
    // see further on in the question for the full class

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return dict.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

.

```
'HashSet2<T>' does not implement interface member
'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'.
'HashSet2<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement
'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'
because it does not have the matching return type of
'System.Collections.IEnumerator'
```

I'd also be grateful for information on fixing it to be more like the standard HashSet if it deviates in it's behaviour or what it implments in ways that could be unexpected.

Continued from: [stackoverflow.com/questions/9966336/c-sharp-xna-xbox-hashset-and-tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966336/c-sharp-xna-xbox-hashset-and-tuple)

The most recent vertion of the class:

```
public class HashSet2<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, Int16> dict;
    // Dictionary<T, bool>

    public HashSet2()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<T, short>();
    }

    public HashSet2(HashSet2<T> from)
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<T, short>();
        foreach (T n in from)
            dict.Add(n, 0);
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        // The key of the dictionary is used but not the value.
        dict.Add(item, 0);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        dict.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return dict.ContainsKey(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(
        T[] array,
        int arrayIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        return dict.Remove(item);
    }

    public System.Collections.IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((System.Collections.IEnumerable)
            dict.Keys).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<T>)
            dict.Keys).GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get {return dict.Keys.Count;}
    }

    public bool IsReadOnly
    {
        get {return false;}
    }
}
```

Comment: You could pull the reference source code for .NET and use it to aid you in your project.

Comment: I've been told that I can't do this here at SO. Apparently it's to do with being closed source.

Comment: @alan2here: you can see the .NET source just fine. Go get `ILSpy` or `Reflector` or some other disassembler, open System.Core.dll and browse to System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray Doesn't sound legal to me. But he could use Mono's hashset, which is published under MIT X11: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Collections.Generic/HashSet.cs

Comment: @CodeInChaos Microsoft effectively tells the developer how to do this by explaining [How to: Step Into a System Call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667409.aspx).

Comment: There are hundreds of errors!

Comment: @JoshuaDrake And where in that article does microsoft say that you may copy and use that code? AFAIK the license for the reference source is *very* restrictive.

Comment: I hate to break it to all of you, but Microsoft has released the source code for the .NET framework a LONG time ago... It can be found at http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx and I use it all the time when I'm curious about how something works in .NET world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enumerate the keys, not the dictionary. Try this:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable)dict.Keys).GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IEnumerable<T>)dict.Keys).GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: I get "'HashSet2<T>' does not implement interface member 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()'. 'HashSet2<T>.GetEnumerator()' cannot implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()' because it does not have the matching return type of 'System.Collections.IEnumerator'."

Comment: IEnumerator and IEnumerable in "public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()" and "return ((IEnumerable)dict.Keys).GetEnumerator();" respectivly give "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type arguments". The class also still gives an error.

Comment: Try `using System.Collections;`

Answer (score 1):

The point is that the HashSet's `GetEnumerator` returns enumerator that enumerates **keys** of type `T` while dictionary's `GetEnumerator` returns enumerator that enumerates KeyValue object.

## UPDATE

Change it to below:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    dict.Keys.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return dict.Keys.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: IEnumerator in "public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()" gives the error "Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>' requires 1 type argument."

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Mono's `HashSet<T>`. You might need to make some minor changes to `#if`, or remove some interfaces/attributes, but it works on .net.

It's using the MIT X11 license, which is permissive. https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Core/System.Collections.Generic/HashSet.cs

Comment: It's a possiblity, although I can't spend loads of time trying to get there library to install and intergrate with my program, editing it to fix it because it's out of date or for the wrong enviroment or uses #if or something which itself breaks more stuff, a day or two in when it's all installed and stuff and there are several more questions here about how to do it, then I eventually give up and still dont have a solution. Thanks for the answer, and I'll look into it, but after I've looked at other possibilities.

Comment: In made the file compile in normal .net 4 in two minutes. It doesn't need any other parts of mono. I had to remove the `DebuggerTypeProxy` attribute, but that's a minor change.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Theres also the how similar to the standard HashSet and if not is it code I can understand so I can change it stuff. Still feels like a potentially recursive can of worms. I think there might be a simpler solution in the answer by Aliostad but it's not quite there. If not I'll reply here later.

Answer (score 0):

Just took a look at the source, and all implementations of GetEnumerator in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` return the `KeyCollection.Enumerator`/`ValueCollection.Enumerator` objects instead of `IEnumerator<T>` (which is what we need). The good news is that the `Key/ValueCollation.Enumerator` implement both `System.Collection.IEnumerator` and `IEnumerator<T>` interfaces, so you can safely cast to those types.

Try doing this instead:

```
public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator)dict.Keys.GetEnumerator();
}

IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
{
    return (IEnumerator<T>)dict.Keys.GetEnumerator();
}
```